# Creating a Electron project with Angular and Knex

Tags: angular, electron, knex.js

Im having problems.

I am trying to create a [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) with [Angular](https://angular.io/) as well as [Knex](https://knexjs.org/) for storage using sqlite3.

I used [angular-electron](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron) and then tried to add a service to angular which would manage the database.

I tried to follow Knex documentation but every time i try to run it i get this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in 'D:\Projects\IonicProjects\testing\angular-electron\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mssql/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mssql' in 'D:\Projects\IonicProjects\testing\angular-electron\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mssql'
ERROR in ./node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mssql/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mssql/lib/base' in 'D:\Projects\IonicProjects\testing\angular-electron\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mssql'
ERROR in ./node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mssql/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mssql/package.json' in 'D:\Projects\IonicProjects\testing\angular-electron\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mssql'
ERROR in ./node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mysql' in 'D:\Projects\IonicProjects\testing\angular-electron\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mysql'
ERROR in ./node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql2/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mysql2' in 'D:\Projects\IonicProjects\testing\angular-electron\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mysql2'
ERROR in ./node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/oracle/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'oracle' in 'D:\Projects\IonicProjects\testing\angular-electron\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\oracle'
ERROR in ./node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/oracledb/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'oracledb' in 'D:\Projects\IonicProjects\testing\angular-electron\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\oracledb'
ERROR in ./node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/postgres/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg' in 'D:\Projects\IonicProjects\testing\angular-electron\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\postgres'
ERROR in ./node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/redshift/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg' in 'D:\Projects\IonicProjects\testing\angular-electron\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\redshift'
ERROR in ./node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/postgres/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg-query-stream' in 'D:\Projects\IonicProjects\testing\angular-electron\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\postgres'
ERROR in ./node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mssql/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tedious' in 'D:\Projects\IonicProjects\testing\angular-electron\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mssql'
```

Could some one point me in the right direction? I have no problem creating a Electron app with Angular for the UI. In other words a Angular app packaged as a desktop app using Electron, but I need a storage solution and would like to use Sqlite3 but have not found any pre-made templates for a project such as this and would like your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't have those libraries installed. Those errors are coming because of non installed database driver packages. Knex doesn't install them automatically and you shouldn't need them all.

If there is webpack configuration related to this, you should be able to ignore most of those libraries and take in only the required driver.

However it could be that you can run the knex lib only in main thread of the electron app so maybe you are trying to pack it with angular which possibly will not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your webpack-config

```
var fs = require("fs");
const nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync("node_modules")
  .filter(x => {
      return [".bin"].indexOf(x) === -1;
})
.forEach(mod => {
        nodeModules[mod] = `commonjs ${mod}`;
    });

module.exports = {
    // ommitted for brevity
    externals: [nodeModules],
}
```